# An object literal cannot have multiple properties with the same name in strict mode React Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have this modal window component. The problem is that when I want to submit some of the modal window props, an error occurs  because of the line below:

```
<form className="modal-content-sizes-form" onSubmit={(e)=>{cartStore.handleSubmitForm(e,{**pizzaStore**.modalProps.name, **pizzaStore**.modalProps.description, **pizzaStore**.size, **pizzaStore**.price, **pizzaStore**.modalProps.ImageUrl})}}>
```

So the question is, what is wrong with writing pizzaStore.modalProps.name? Because this doesn't let the app compile
Here is the full code of the component:

```
import React from 'react'
import pizzaStore from './stores/PizzaStore'
import {observer} from "mobx-react-lite"
import cartStore from './stores/CartStore';
import { action } from 'mobx';

function ModalWindowComponent({activeModal, setActiveModal}:any){
    
    const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption]=React.useState("small")
    const handleSetOption=(e:any)=>{
            setSelectedOption(e.target.value);
            pizzaStore.setSize(selectedOption);
            pizzaStore.setPrice(selectedOption)
        }
        

    return (
        <div className={activeModal?"modal active":"modal"}  onClick={()=>{setActiveModal(false); setSelectedOption("small")}}>
            <div className="modal-content" onClick={(e)=>{e.stopPropagation()}}>
                <div className="modal-content-header">
                    <button onClick={()=>setActiveModal(false)}>Close</button>
                </div>
                <img src={pizzaStore.modalProps.modalImageUrl} className="modal-content-img"/>
                <p className="modal-content-pizza-name">{pizzaStore.modalProps.name}</p>
                <p className="modal-content-pizza-desc">{pizzaStore.modalProps.description}</p>
                <p className="modal-content-pizza-size">{pizzaStore.size}см</p>
                <p className="modal-content-pizza-weight">{pizzaStore.setWeight(selectedOption)}грамм</p>
                <p className="modal-content-pizza-price">{pizzaStore.price}Руб.</p>
                <form className="modal-content-sizes-form" onSubmit={(e:any)=>{cartStore.handleSubmitForm(e,{pizzaStore.modalProps.name, pizzaStore.modalProps.description, pizzaStore.size, pizzaStore.price, pizzaStore.modalProps.ImageUrl})}}>
                    <label>
                    
                    <input  name="radio-size"value="small" type="radio" onChange={handleSetOption} checked={!activeModal||selectedOption==="small"} className="modal-content-sizes-form-option"/>Маленькая</label>
                    <label>
                    <input  name="radio-size"value="medium" type="radio"  onChange={handleSetOption}checked={selectedOption==="medium"}className="modal-content-sizes-form-option"/>Средняя</label>
                    <label>
                    <input name="radio-size"value="big" type="radio"  onChange={handleSetOption}checked={selectedOption==="big"} className="modal-content-sizes-form-option"/>Большая</label>
                    <button onClick={()=>{setActiveModal(false);console.log(cartStore.cartItems, pizzaStore.price)}}>Добавить</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default observer(ModalWindowComponent)
```

Comment: `{pizzaStore.modalProps.name, pizzaStore.modalProps.description, pizzaStore.size, pizzaStore.price, pizzaStore.modalProps.ImageUrl}` this isn't valid js

Comment: then what would make it valid?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: so the thing is I want to pass the object that you mentioned earlier to the cart state array in the Mobx cartStore through the handleSubmitForm method which contains another method of submitPropsToArr but the compiler underlines all the pizzaStore mentions in the object and the app doesn't compile with the "An object literal cannot have multiple properties with the same name in strict mode" error. I don't have any idea what is wrong, so I seek for solution